# Azure - Idle VMs from cli

Tags: powershell, azure

is there a way to see identify the idle vms from a cli with either Azure PS or Azure CLi? if there is no way to look for "idle status", is there an option to get the cpu % usage? or memory % usage?

Answer (score 0):

Azure doesn't know what your definition of Idle is, so it can't just show a machine as Idle, instead you will need to look at metrics that make sense to you, so CPU usage, disk usage etc.

Fortunately the recently announced azure monitor service allows you to retrieve these metrics directly from teh Azure API, including via PowerShell or CLI.

For example, you can get CPU metrics with something similar to this:

```
$endTime = Get-Date

$startTime = $endTime.AddMinutes(-40)

$timeGrain = ’00:01:00′

$resourceId = ‘/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_guid/resourceGroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM’

$metricName = ‘\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time’



(Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $resourceId `
-TimeGrain $timeGrain -StartTime $startTime `
-EndTime $endTime `
-MetricNames $metricName).MetricDefinitions
```

See [this MSDN article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-powershell-samples/) for more details on PowerShell commands

Comment: Tried, didn't get any results. The VM is up and running. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the Azure portal metrics section to check you can see metrics from that VM. If you can then use the docs to debug your powershell to find the problem.